# paypal payment in android studio

Tags: java, android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

when i install `PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK` my payment is fine and of course on paypal sandbox wont save this transaction, to save the transaction i need to switch to `PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` but i get error like this:

> System error, please try again one last time.

The client ID I provided is correct and my paypal personal sandbox account is correct (I checked them on the website, I wrote with paypal bar and it works. works fine) but I don't understand why via android studio I get this error and where did I go wrong? below is all my code

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnPay;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId("AYjsqsGPCffv-niyJYub6xbIQA_8dhRTJbGG0HWVk8p7VX3GR8iOzMEk1HfgkKNw1wWScgXnt0OSC6Pv");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPay = findViewById(R.id.btnPay);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

        btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBuyPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(){
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10),
                "USD","BINDAI PAYPAL",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null){
                try {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    Toast.makeText(this, "payment success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment or ...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnPay"
    android:text="Paypal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // SDK PAYPAL - START
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.6'
    // SDK PAYPAL - END

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

my paypal account:

```
username: bindai243156@gmail.com
Password: Bindai243156
```

(This is just the account I created to demo for the paypal payment function, inside this account there are sandbox accounts to test)

Answer (score 0):

Set your device's local time correctly.

Comment: I just tried this paypal technology for the first time, so I'm not very familiar with it, can you be more specific? Thank you!